# How to use warpPerspective for a single coordinate of Mat

Tags: c++, opencv

I successfully found the homography matrix between 2 images using:

```
Mat H = findHomography(mpts_2, mpts_1, RANSAC, 1, outlier_mask);
```

Now, with the given Mat H I wan't to find the transformation for the four corner points of an image.
So how can I get the transformation for these points using warpPerspective()?!? Or do I have to use the transform() function?

I need the transformation of this points to get the intersection of the warped image with the original image.
Thanks in advance for you efforts...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are interested in [`perspectiveTransform(...)`](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/core_operations_on_arrays.html#perspectiveTransform). It is analogous to `warpPerspective(...)` only it operates on vectors, not on an entire image.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Should look more often into the documentation ;)